# Regex to check for at least 2 characters somewhere in the string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to create a regex that makes sure the text has at least 2 characters in it.

So far I have this:

`"([A-Za-z0-9]{2})+"`

But it requires the characters to be right next to each other.

I need a code that matches this: `.e.3.`

Comment: First define character. I assume you mean letter or number and not characters like `.`?

Comment: Something like `([A-Za-z0-9].*){2,}` ?

Comment: Add the dot to the character class and change the quantifier to `{2,}` like `^[A-Za-z0-9.]{2,}` Or if the characters should be divided by a dot `^\.(?:[A-Za-z0-9]\.){2,}`

Comment: Matching the regular expression `..` is sufficient to verify that "the text has at least 2 characters in it." You could also just check that the length of the string is at least `2`. If there are additional requirements, such as a restriction on which characters may be present in the string or that the two characters are the same character, or that the two characters are the same specific character, or that the two characters equal two specified characters, or something else, that needs to be specified in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for this.

See this code in use [here](https://tio.run/##TY6xCsJADIbn3lMcndrBWxyLU12EioKD83mGGmjvNEkFkT77ea0F/Zaf8CXhd7xygSDGgdG3@vRigb5S/5Np0D8qlU2o@3Dp0GnXWWZ9pNCS7dVb6cSiWKykeAa86r1FX5Sz/e5kLDR9TqE3Ojdg1iavZjWBXrRLImlTh8FL4W6WzI4bEAE60BZblPJ3UAfPoQNzJhRIPaFwix3VGOMH)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string str = ".e.3.";
        int c = str.Count(char.IsLetterOrDigit);
        Console.WriteLine(c);
    }
}
```

Outputs `2`

Comment: Why the downvote? Does exactly what OP is asking for.

Comment: Countered that with an upvote. Regex should never be a goal on itself.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis thank you - my thoughts exactly. Regex is the right solution when another solution doesn't exist or performance/code management is an issue